# cant find default Enviroment Settings menu in Godot 4

Tags: godot

i cant find the default enviroment settings in the newest version of Godot 4, someone please help as there is nothing that i can find about it. i have atached a screenshot
https://ibb.co/wYbCPGK

tried. updating, restarting and uninstalling and reinstalling